# Laravel access control layer and middle ware

Tags: php, roles, laravel-5.5

If I am creating a table of roles in which I am giving roles **(admin/employee/supervisor)** and corresponding field **(read/write/update/delete)** **access and assign these roles to users** how to use this in Laravel way? Please give me an example for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far friend?

Comment: i have tried the normal way of using  construct and hard coded  and compared the value using auth ...not able to find good example according to my need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out this package which is really known in the Laravel community

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission